# Why is it a bad idea to refresh JUST token on every request?

Tags: laravel, reactjs, react-redux, jwt

So I'm building a React app with a Laravel API, and the JWT token is expiring every hour (as it's meant to).

Now, I've read a few different approaches to refreshing the token on here, all of which sound really convoluted (storing the expiry in state, doing a second request whenever the API returns a 401 etc), but everyone seems to think it's a horrible idea to just refresh the token on every request.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with React, but in terms of JWT, the main reason I can think of is that you would have to include the new token in every response. This forces all your endpoints to act as authorization endpoints, as well as whatever their main purpose is. I think it's better to keep your authorization endpoint seperate from other API endpoints, and just make requests to that when it's necessary to refresh.